# How can I print only numbers inside a tag

Tags: beautifulsoup

I have a soup object like:

```
<div class="list-card__select">
                            
            <div class="list-card__item-size">
            Size:
            75 м²        </div>
```

I did

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml')
number = item.find(class_='list-card__item-size').text
print(number)
```

Result: 'Size: 75 м²'

How can I get just: '75'

Comment: It would be always a good idea, also to add an url of the website to your question, cause sometimes information is still present in the right format in other elements or api or javascript

Comment: https://shop.onduline.ru/catalog/ondutis/?page=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that the pattern is always identical, a simple `split()` can be used.

```
item.find(class_='list-card__item-size').text.split(' ')[1]
```

Alternatives can be `regex` or you inspect other `elements`, `javascript` or `api` that hold this information directly.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
data = soup.findAll("span", { "class":"comments" })
numbers = [d.text for d in data]
```

Answer (score 1):

If number is always positive then we also can use re package.

```
import re

string = "Size: 75 м²"
print( re.findall(r'\d+', string)[0] )
```

Output : 75